# How do I create sample security issues on Docker?

Tags: docker, security, kubernetes, trivy

I'm trying to create an assignment for students to do that contains the following :

1. A docker image with issues that have to be scanned and remedied. (using an opensource scanner in kubernetes)
2. (Maybe) A sample attack scenario that can exploit those vulnerabilities.

The problem arises when I try to find a suitable vulnerable image or create one. I cannot find a base of security issues at all. I really bend my back thinking of a suitable phrase in Google but everything leads merely to some blog posts about how-to scan an image.
I expected a database that might contain multiple sec issues and what causes them. I'd also expect some way to discern which are the most popular ones.

Do you have the source I require ?
Maybe you can just offer me 3-4 common security issues that are good to know and educational when having your first brush with docker ? (And how to create those issues ?)

The whole situation would have been probably easier if I myself would have been an expert in the field, but the thing I do is also my assignment as a student. (So as students we design assignments for each other. )

Comment: Take a look at https://www.aquasec.com/products/container-security/,I am sure there are plenty orf resources here that can somehow help you.

Comment: You could pick a security vulnerability like [Log4J's RCE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44832), find a version of Log4J which is vulnerable to this attack, and install it into an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for the **Container security hardening** and Kubernetes security options maybe.

You can use some tools like

- [kubesec](https://github.com/controlplaneio/kubesec) - Security risk analysis for Kubernetes resources
- [checkov](https://github.com/bridgecrewio/checkov) - Prevent cloud misconfigurations and find vulnerabilities during build-time in infrastructure as code, container images and open-source packages
- [Trivy](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy) - vulnerabilities, misconfigurations, secrets, SBOM in containers, Kubernetes, code repositories, clouds and more

If you are looking for some questions you can set like, this is CKS (Certified Kubernetes Security) exam question

- There are a number of pods/container running in the "spectacle" namespace.
  Identify and delete the pods which have CRITICAL vulnerabilities.

For this **trivy** opensource tools comes into the picture to scan the image that you will be using in the deployment of Kubernetes or docker

```
trivy image --severity CRITICAL nginx:1.16 (Image running in container)
```

List of few questions you can create lab out of it : https://github.com/moabukar/CKS-Exercises-Certified-Kubernetes-Security-Specialist/tree/main/7-mock-exam-questions